# Problema "Fizzbuzz" sobre detectar si un número es divisible por 3 o 5

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy aprendiendo javascript y no sé qué está mal en mi problema sobre:

- Imprimir "Bizz" si un número es múltiplo de 5
- "Fizz" si es múltiplo de 3
- "FizzBizz", si es múltiplo de ambos

Esto es lo que llevo:

```js
var i=1
while (i<=100) {
  if (i % 5==0) {
    console.log("Bizz");
  } else if (i % 3==0) {
    console.log("Fizz");
  } else if (i % 3==0 && i % 5==0) {
    console.log("FizzBizz");
  } else {
    console.log("Número", i);
  }
  i=i+1
}
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es que primero verificas si el número es múltiplo de `5`, de lo contrario, si es múltiplo de `3`.

Ejemplo, imagina la llegada del número `30` (que es múltiplo de `3` y `5`), éste número ingresaría a la primera condición (múltiplo de `5`) y no a la condición de que es múltiplo de `3` y `5`, ya que esta condición **está al final**.

Solo tendrías que cambiar el orden de tus `if`, ya que primero debe verificar si el número coincidir con ambos (múltiplo de 3 y 5), si no ocurre, compara con el siguiente múltiplo, así sucesivamente:

```js
var i = 1;
while (i <= 100) {
  if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
    console.log('FizzBizz');
  } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
    console.log('Bizz');
  } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
    console.log('Fizz');
  } else {
    console.log('Número', i);
  }
  i = i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Para ahorrarte tantas condicionales y palabras, puedes escribir todo con dos `if` consecutivos y concatenar:

```js
var message = ""
for (numero = 1; numero <= 100; numero++) {
    console.log("Numero: " + numero)
    if (numero % 3 == 0) message += "Fizz"
    if (numero % 5 == 0) message += "Bizz"
    if (message) {
        console.log(message);
        message = ""
    }
}
```

Primero creamos una pequeña cadena como buffer.

Luego:

- Si primero es múltiplo de 3, le concatenamos la cadena "Fizz"
- Si luego resulta ser que es múltiplo de 5, le concatenamos "Bizz"
- Si no cumple ninguna de las condiciones no se le añade nada y sigue siendo la cadena vacía.

Al final imprimimos el resultado final no sin antes checar si hay algún mensaje vacío para evitar imprimir saltos de línea a lo tonto.

A diferencia de las otras respuestas, yo opto un poco por la limpieza del output y saltarme unas condicionales... a cambio, añado una validación y concatenaciones.

Algun experto en JS me dirá que tan limpio o eficiente es hacer esto.

Answer (score -1):

Para encontrar los múltiplos de `3` y `5` en JavaScript, se puede utilizar un ciclo `for` para iterar desde `1` hasta un número determinado (por ejemplo, `100`) y verificar si el número actual es divisible tanto por `3` como por `5`. Si lo es, se puede agregar a un array o imprimir en la consola. Aquí hay un ejemplo de código:

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
    console.log(i + " es múltiplo de 3 y 5");
  }
}
```

Este código imprimirá en la consola todos los números desde 1 a 100 que sean múltiplos tanto de 3 como de 5.

Comment: No es lo que pide el usuario. El código debe emitir tres mensajes distintos según el número sea divisible por 3, 5 o ambos.